# Alias for a specific symbol within a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I would like to use specific symbols from a namespace with short syntax, but without resorting to `using namespace <xyz>;` as that brings in all symbols to the current scope. For example, the idea (that doesn't compile) would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using cout = std::cout;
using endl = std::endl;
cout << "this is a test" << endl;
```

Can this be done? This seems trivial, but I can't find an example. An alternative is to `#define cout std::cout`, but I'd like to avoid that because it needs to be `#undef`'ed. All C++ versions are permitted.

Also, `cout` is a template class instantiation and `endl` is a template function instantiation, so perhaps the method of aliasing will differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a possibility, you can simply write:

```
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
```

Comment: Well now I foolish having written up this question, but thank you.

Comment: Some features of C++ are difficult to find, because you have no keyword to search for.